# Datanucleus type_converter plugin

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

I created a converter plugin like described [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/extensions/type_converter.html) for a type X.

Then I created the class

```
class A {
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.Eager)
    X x;
}
```

When I try to persist an A object I get the following error

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: Object of type net.sf.jcommon.geo.Country isnt Serializable
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.AbstractLargeBinaryRDBMSMapping.setObject(AbstractLargeBinaryRDBMSMapping.java:235)
org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.SingleFieldMapping.setObject(SingleFieldMapping.java:207)
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.fieldmanager.ParameterSetter.storeObjectField(ParameterSetter.java:201)
org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.providedObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:1447)
```

The plugin seems to be loaded as far as I can see from the logging.

```
Added converter for X<->java.lang.String using mypackage.myplugin.XStringConverter
```

Using debugger, I set breakpoints into the converter, but the flow does not go there.

What else could have went wrong?

I'm using DataNucleus 3.1.3.

The plugin code follows.

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: myplugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: mypackage.myplugin
Bundle-Version: 1.0.1
Bundle-Vendor: Adrian Ber
```

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugin id="mypackage.myplugin" name="DataNucleus plug-ins" provider-name="myplugin">
<extension point="org.datanucleus.type_converter">
    <type-converter name="dn.x-string" member-type="mypackage.myplugin" 
        datastore-type="java.lang.String"
        converter-class="mypackage.myplugin.XStringConverter" />
</extension>
</plugin>
```

XStringConverter

```
package mypackage.myplugin;
import org.datanucleus.store.types.converters.TypeConverter;

public class XStringConverter implements TypeConverter<X, String> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public String toDatastoreType(Country memberValue) {
    return memberValue == null ? null : memberValue.getISO();
}

@Override
public Country toMemberType(String datastoreValue) {
    return  datastoreValue == null ? null : X.findByISO(datastoreValue.trim());
}
}
```

Comment: Does your class X implement Serializable?

Comment: No, it does not. But if I have a converter for that class to String, I think it shouldn't.

Comment: if you created a plugin, then why not post it ... converter, plugin.xml, MANIFEST.MF etc. And state whether you provided the associated XXXMapping class for it (for RDBMS datastores, essential in 3.1, optional in 3.2)

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comment to the question, you need to provide the RDBMS JavaTypeMapping plugin too, since without that the TypeConverter is not used. Just write a simple JavaTypeMapping that extends ObjectAsStringMapping, and uses your TypeConverter.

In DN 3.2 the JavaTypeMapping is not essential, and a TypeConverter is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `implements Serializable` to your class X.

Comment: Then the field will be serialized as binary, not as String. And most importantly, not using the converter.

Comment: In the example DataNucleus gives, URI implements Serializable. The conversion happens because you specify it in plugin.xml.